# How to add smooth Player Movement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, unity-webgl

I have added the player movement in the `Update()` function using the code below:

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    transform.position += transform.right * (Time.deltaTime * 5);
}
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    transform.position -= transform.right * (Time.deltaTime * 5);
}
```

This works, however, the movement is choppy. The user would have to click on the left arrow **multiple times** to have the object move left and the same for the right arrow. I want to have the user click on the left arrow while the object keeps moving left until the left arrow is released. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Use `GetKey` instead of `GetKeyDown`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Input.GetKey("KeyName")` instead of `Input.GetKeyDown("KeyName")`.

According to Unity's [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html), `GetKeyDown` will return `true` only when the button is pressed not when you are holding it down. If you want to move the game object continuously when the button is pressed you need to use the `GetKey` method.

Answer (score -1):

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.smoothdeltatime* 5);
transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.smoothdeltatime* 5);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.